# Kill ITunes Splash Screen

Tags: ipad

After selecting "music" and listennig to an album, every time I wake my IPad3, there is a giant album-cover splash screen which remains until I unlock the IPad.  I really don't like that.  How do I convince the IPad to cease and desist with album-cover art when I'm waking it?

I don't mind looking at album-cover art, but only when I'm explicitly running the built-in music app.   Perhaps I just need to shut down the music app?  Is there a way to do this (to shut down an app)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fully close an app double tapping HOME to get the recent apps list (note that unless you are at the home screen, the currently running app won't be listed) and then tap and holding on any App icon until you get the wiggles - at this point hit the minus sign against any app in your recent list.  This will either stop the app, if it is currently performing any background task, or remove the 'fast resume' saved state so that upon the next start it will not resume where it left off.